# How to record high quality vocal with Adobe audition

Tags: adobe-audition, production-mixing, rode

this is my first post in this sound stack exchange community, I have bought rode nt1 and AI1 studio kit, I have set it up in my bedroom, so I am using Adobe audition for vocal recording but somehow i am not satisfied with the recorded vocals let me show you my settings -

Device class - MME,
Device input - RODE AI1 INTERFACE,
Device output - external speakers connected to my laptop,
Sample rate - 44100,
Bit depth - 32,
Recording in mono
And while recording in multitrack session I change the option of default multitrack session to mono-> and rode channel 1

I just wanted to ask what additional things I need to do so that I can get alteast audio quality close to like studios(as in studio they use pre amp and lot of equipment so getting that quality is an exception).
Keeping in mind the audio which I am recording that will go for mixing mastering for a song.

Comment: There are many different issues that can affect audio quality and many different opinions about what constitutes "high quality" in vocal recording. Can you tell us what it is about your current recordings that you don't like?

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir, okay let me tell u like I have rode nt1 mic and rode AI1 interface which is around price 33k. What I usually do is record the audio in my home, and then I send the song in we transfer to the music producer who then mixes it and send me back the final song. The guy whom I sent he has bm 800 mic in his home studio and which is only 8k. So according to that my mic should produce a way better sound than him right?. But when he release any song which is recorded in his bm 800 mic that's sound awesome compared to my song which I record in my home :( I hope u get it.

Comment: Is there any secret behind recording clear vocals, or recording software matters like FL , Cubase, logic Pro records good vocals in comparison to adobe audition?

Comment: There are so many factors, that there are entire college courses on doing this. A 33k interface is not necessarily better for what you want than a 1k interface. You do need to learn how to use every piece of kit you have, and that is not going to be able to be covered in a Stack Exchange question. You need to be aware of the room you are recording in, mic, distance to mic, input gain stage/preamp, audio interface, EQ, software, hardware spec, audio format used, what the producer wants, etc. Many of these are covered in various questions here - please browse for more.

Comment: @RoryAlsop thanks for the info. just to let u know that my interface is not 33k actualy the entire studio kit costs 33k which includes mic and interface :)

Comment: btw, prices in "k" are not very useful unless we know the currency. "33k" in UK Pounds or US Dollars would buy quite a rig indeed. The same "33k" in Indian Rupees would be 1/10th the value.

Comment: @Tetsujin apologies for mentioning the price in k, it is 451 USD

Answer (score 2):

Without more specific information I can only offer you a generalised suggestion:

A good microphone goes a long way to getting an ***accurate*** recording but that doesn't always mean it sounds good or fits well with your track.

**Good microphone technique** and **voice control** are important: if you can't sound like you mean it then it doesn't matter what you do electronically, it's just not going to sound right.

Try using some gentle **compression** to even out some of the dynamics in the vocals. This will make it easier to mix because the levels will be more stable.

Add in a little **reverb**. This will soften the edges and help the vocal track feel more like a part of the rest of the music.

These are the most basic things I do to any vocal track before I even consider any creative processing. Raw recordings can sound lifeless and dull, adding in a little compression and reverb helps them to breathe again.

Comment: thanks for replying, i just wanted to ask do DAWs matter while recording, like i use adobe audition so it might not give clear vocals, so i should use FL or Cubase or logic pro to get good vocals? Is it true or a myth.

Comment: The DAW you choose won't affect the sound directly. In a DAW, everything is digital: There are no unintentional changes to the sound. The only differences are the bit rate (how many slices of sound per second) and the bit depth (how many different levels of sound each slice can represent). CDs are typically 16bit (65,535 levels) at 44.1kHz (44,100 slices per second), and FLAC files are usually 24bit (8,388,607 levels) at 96kHz (96,000 slices per second). Most DAWs can reproduce these but, the denser the digital data, the longer the DAW will take to process it.

Comment: thanks, so suppose if i record 3 vocal takes using 3 different daws(A, B, C) with same settings, upon mixing those 3 raw vocals in a different daw(say D) gives same quality of audio?

Comment: If you use the same bit rate and depth settings on all of them for both input and output they should be identical. However, I should also stress that, for a truly scientific test, you would need to use the same sound in the same room with the same mic and preprocessing to eliminate any other changes. Choice of DAW is usually based on workflow rather than any supposed sound difference.